# WordPress: retroactively add parent category

Tags: wordpress

I have a WP installation with Custom Post Types. My CPT has custom taxonomy. When adding posts, we only added child categories to posts and left the parent category unselected.

Is it possible to automatically add the parent category retroactively to the post? The child category should stay the primary category. I don't want to edit all 200+ posts by hand.

Answer (score 0):

You should loop through your posts and apply (append) the new category. Something like this:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'myposttype'
 );

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
        wp_set_post_categories(newcat_ID, true)
    endwhile;
}

wp_reset_query();
```